# div no se ajusta al tamaño de su contenido

Tags: css

Estoy peleándome con 1 div en su CSS in line implemente estas 3 opciones:

#1

```
<div style="padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
```

#2

```
<div style="position: relative; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
```

#3

```
<div style="position: absolute; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
```

el problema esta en que el este div no cubre el 100% del ancho que si cubre sus elementos hijos y hay un scroll horizontal, estoy utilizando una etiqueta `code` que contiene etiquetas `span` y que a su vez contienen espacios `html` (`&nbsp;`) que no debo tocar, como hago para que este div cubra esos espacios?:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 97vh;
        }

        .helper {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: scroll;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="helper">
        <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
                <code><span style="color: rgb(102,217,239); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">
                <span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;"></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Theme:&nbsp;(Red)|&nbsp;Given&nbsp;Variable&nbsp;|&nbsp;Type:&nbsp;object&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">$given_var&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=(object)[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;object&nbsp;node&nbsp;of&nbsp;Class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;implement&nbsp;of&nbsp;traits:&nbsp;talkWorld.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'__construct'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'sayHello'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">];&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;[BOH]&nbsp;Basic&nbsp;Output&nbsp;Handler&nbsp;for&nbsp;PHP&nbsp;-&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;2020&nbsp;-&nbsp;2021&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>//&nbsp;Open&nbsp;Source&nbsp;Project&nbsp;Developed&nbsp;by&nbsp;Icaros&nbsp;Net.&nbsp;S.A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
                </code>
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="helper">
        Otro Sitio.
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Resultado actual y resultado esperado que cubra los espacios faltantes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que quieres lograr. Puedes adjuntar una imagen del resultado esperado?

Comment: @JheymanMejia el resultado esperado no lo he logrado, lo que tengo es una imagen de la sección que el div no cubre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez puedas utilizar flex para que el div helper cubra todo el código, algo así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 97vh;
        }

        .helper {
            display: flex;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: scroll;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="helper">
        <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
                <code><span style="color: rgb(102,217,239); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">
                <span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;"></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Theme:&nbsp;(Red)|&nbsp;Given&nbsp;Variable&nbsp;|&nbsp;Type:&nbsp;object&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">$given_var&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=(object)[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;object&nbsp;node&nbsp;of&nbsp;Class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;implement&nbsp;of&nbsp;traits:&nbsp;talkWorld.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'__construct'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'sayHello'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">];&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;[BOH]&nbsp;Basic&nbsp;Output&nbsp;Handler&nbsp;for&nbsp;PHP&nbsp;-&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;2020&nbsp;-&nbsp;2021&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>//&nbsp;Open&nbsp;Source&nbsp;Project&nbsp;Developed&nbsp;by&nbsp;Icaros&nbsp;Net.&nbsp;S.A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
                </code>
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="helper">
        Otro Sitio.
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: gracias, en teoría no quería tocar ningún css o elemento diferente al div hijo del helper; por lo había resuelto mesclando position relative con float left, pero pensaba que se podia resolver con otro metodo veo que el tuyo lo resuelve pero toca el CSS de otro elemento.

Answer (score 2):

A pesar de haber escogido otra respuesta como solución, tambien les dejo esta: si por si acaso no desean tocar ningún otro elemento o CSS hay que mesclar `position: relative` y en este caso `float: left`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        .container {
            height: 97vh;
        }

        .helper {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: scroll;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="helper">
        <div style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); border-radius: 10px;">
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
                <code><span style="color: rgb(102,217,239); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">
                <span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;"></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Theme:&nbsp;(Red)|&nbsp;Given&nbsp;Variable&nbsp;|&nbsp;Type:&nbsp;object&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(189,063,075); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">$given_var&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=(object)[&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;object&nbsp;node&nbsp;of&nbsp;Class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;implement&nbsp;of&nbsp;traits:&nbsp;talkWorld.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'__construct'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">'sayHello'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">=&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(189,008,025); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">"no&nbsp;parameters"</span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;Method&nbsp;of&nbsp;class:&nbsp;MyHelloWorld,&nbsp;modifiers:&nbsp;(public),&nbsp;return&nbsp;type:&nbsp;undefined.&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,254,254); font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(072,000,017); white-space: nowrap;">];&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span><span style="color: rgb(254,172,002); background-color: rgb(072,000,017); font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">//&nbsp;[BOH]&nbsp;Basic&nbsp;Output&nbsp;Handler&nbsp;for&nbsp;PHP&nbsp;-&nbsp;Copyright&nbsp;2020&nbsp;-&nbsp;2021&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>//&nbsp;Open&nbsp;Source&nbsp;Project&nbsp;Developed&nbsp;by&nbsp;Icaros&nbsp;Net.&nbsp;S.A&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
                </code>
            <!--NO Tocar esto es automatico-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="helper">
        Otro Sitio.
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```